# Invertbility of an element in a subalgebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, morphism

Let $A$ be a unital algebra over the complex numbers and $B$ be a subalgebra of $A$ with $A=B + \Bbb{C}1_A$. Suppose that $B$ has a unit $1_B \neq 1_A$ and that $\lambda \in \Bbb{C}\setminus  \{0\}$. The book I'm reading claims:

$$b + \lambda 1_A  \mathrm{\ invertible \ in \ A} \iff b + \lambda 1_B  \mathrm{\ invertible \ in \ B} $$

I have trouble showing the implication $\implies $ . Suppose $b+ \lambda 1_A$ has inverse $c$ in $A$. What is the inverse of $b+ \lambda 1_B $ in $B$, or if an explicit inverse can't be written down how can one show it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $b+u1_A$ is invertible, $(b+u1_A)(b'+u'1_A)=1_A=bb'+u'b+ub'+uu'1_A$ since $B$ is a subalgebra $bb'+u'b+ub'=0, uu'=1$ and $(b+u1_B)(b'+u'1_B)=1_B$.

Comment: Typo? Shouldn't it be $bb' + bu' + ub' + uu'1_A?$

Comment: $u$ is a scalar and $u1_A$ is in the center.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks!